# URL schemes of common iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I'd like to know if there is a list of custom URL schemes for the most popular iOS apps, such as Keynote, Numbers, Pages, Evernote, etc. I'd also like to know what parameters to use for these URLs.

The reason I need this is that I have an app on the App Store, and most users are asking me to provide 'Open With...' functionality from within the app once they select a file from their iCloud Drive.

Comment: try to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to implement "Open With..." functionality

Comment: This site isn't for advertising your app. It's for asking questions. That is why your app link is being removed. The app reference has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: I don't need to advertise a completely free app! All I wanted is for the readers to get a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using schemes you should use [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/index.html).

If you want to open a file, you would instantiate it like this:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController * controller= [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:yourFileURL];
```

and then you can present it with:

```
[controller presentOpenInMenuFromRect:yourRect inView:yourView animated:YES ];
```

Here is a [tutorial with demo project](http://pinkstone.co.uk/tag/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/)

Comment: Thank you! Also kudos to @phix23 for suggesting that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a website which does exactly that: http://handleopenurl.com/.

Unfortunately, it lacks the information about parameters needed for the URLs. You can find some  of them on [this wiki](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes).

Comment: This is not what the OP actually needs to meet the needs requested by their customers.

Comment: Thank you Michal, this is really useful. I ended up using UIDocumentInteractionController however.

Comment: This website doesn't exist (anymore).